# SignalR Long Running Process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have setup a SignalR hub which has the following method:

```
    public void SomeFunction(int SomeID)
    {

        try
        {

            Thread.Sleep(600000);

            Clients.Caller.sendComplete("Complete");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // Exception Handling
        }
        finally
        {
             // Some Actions
        }

        m_Logger.Trace("*****Trying To Exit*****");
    }
```

The issue I am having is that SignalR initiates and defaults to Server Sent Events and then hangs.  Even though the function/method exits minutes later (10 minutes) the method is initiated again ( > 3 minutes) even when the sendComplete and hub.stop() methods are initiated/called on the client prior.  Should the user stay on the page the initial "/send?" request stays open indefinitely.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid blocking the method for so long, you could use a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task)and call the client method asynchronously.

```
public void SomeFunction(Int32 id)
{
  var connectionId = this.Context.ConnectionId;
  Task.Delay(600000).ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    var message = String.Format("The operation has completed. The ID was: {0}.", id);
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SomeHub>();
    context.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendComplete(message);
  });
}
```

Hubs are created when request arrives and destroyed after response is sent down the wire, so in the continuation task, you need to create a new context for yourself to be able to work with a client by their connection identifier, since the original hub instance will no longer be around to provide you with the `Clients` method.

Also note that you can leverage the nicer syntax that uses `async` and `await` keywords for describing asynchronous program flow. See examples at [The ASP.NET Site's SignalR Hubs API Guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#asyncmethods).